# Twitter JSON search specified for my own username

Tags: android, json, search, twitter

For my Twitter RSS reader I got this link:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q="psvhandbal"&rpp=10&page=1
```

This gives me the results of all tweets containing psvhandbal, what I want is only the tweets posted by psvhandbal, can I edit this link so that it only displays psvhandbal's tweets?

EDIT

I already found it!

Easy as can be:

```
search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:psvhandbal
```

Just needed to at the "from:"-part

Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for statuses posted by a specific user in this fashion (example uses one of National Geographic's twitter accounts)

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?id=NatGeo
```

The documentation of this can be found [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) - there are many other options. This will by default return the latest 20 status updates.

Comment: Sadly that did not work in my Android app based on: http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/android-programming-tutorial-a-simple-twitter-feed-reader/

Comment: @LarsVandeDonk You won't simply be able to paste it into your code. You will need to read the documentation to see the format of the JSON response you get and adapt your code to filter and display it. Edit: I see you've found a solution that does return it in the same format :)